Printing multiple lines from the line containing a pattern with awk (error with if statement)
I want to print 3 lines starting from the line which contains a specific pattern.  For example, if my input file input.txt looks like this,
1
2
3
4
pattern1
5
6
8
9
10

I want awk to print
pattern1
5
6

How should I do it? I tried awk '/pattern1/{cnt=1} if(cnt != 0 && cnt<3) {cnt = cnt+1} if(cnt == 3){cnt=0} if(cnt >0){print $0}' inputfile.txt, but it doesn't work. It gives me this error and I can't figure out what's wrong.
awk: cmd. line:1: /pattern1/{cnt=1} if(cnt != 0 && cnt<3) {cnt = cnt+1} if(cnt ==3){cnt=0} if(cnt >0) {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /pattern1/{cnt=1} if(cnt != 0 && cnt<3) {cnt = cnt+1} if(cnt ==3){cnt=0} if(cnt >0) {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /pattern1/{cnt=1} if(cnt != 0 && cnt<3) {cnt = cnt+1} if(cnt ==3){cnt=0} if(cnt >0) {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                          ^ syntax error


Can pattern1 occur multiple times in the input and, if so, should it be matched multiple times or only the first or only the last or something else? Never actually use the word "pattern" for pattern-matching by the way as that's like going to a car/truck/motorcycle sales store and only telling them you want a "vehicle" or asking someone to go to a grocery store for you to just buy "food", see how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern.

You may use this awk:
awk -v n=3 '/pattern1/{limit = NR + n} NR < limit' file

pattern1
5
6

However this task, grep would be shorter:
grep 'pattern1' -A 2 file

pattern1
5
6


Ah, thank you very much! But I'm curious why my original stupid try didn't work :).


what's wrong

In GNU AWK if is one of Control Statements in Actions and as such is designed to be used inside action (that is inside {...}) whilst in this code
awk '/pattern1/{cnt=1} if(cnt != 0 && cnt<3) {cnt = cnt+1} if(cnt == 3){cnt=0} if(cnt >0){print $0}' inputfile.txt

all ifs are outside actions. You do not need ifs in such case as relational expression is valid pattern, therefore following
awk '/pattern1/{cnt=1}(cnt != 0 && cnt<3){cnt = cnt+1}(cnt == 3){cnt=0}(cnt >0){print $0}' inputfile.txt

is correct syntax-wise, but w.r.t to desired output it is not.

want to print 3 lines starting from the line which contains a specific
pattern

getline is handy for that task, it could be used for that task following way
awk '/pattern1/{print;if(getline){print};if(getline){print}}' inputfile.txt

Explanation: in case end of file is reached getline returns false value, so I used ifs to prevent printing last line multiple times.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
